# How can I remove an animation in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <form class="form">
     <label>How much do you want to donate</label>
      <input type="number" id="k">
<button type="button" id="l">Cal</button>

    </form>
    <script type="module">
    import * as THREE from "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.121.1/build/three.module.js";
import { OrbitControls } from "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.121.1/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js";
let s;

function animates(){ 
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

const scene = new THREE.Scene();
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
75,
window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
0.1,
1000
);
const controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

const grid = new THREE.Group();

const cubeSize = 0.5;
const size = Math.cbrt(s);
const gap = 0.01;

const geometry = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry(
cubeSize,
cubeSize,
cubeSize
);
const material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();
const cubes = new THREE.InstancedMesh(
geometry,
material,
Math.pow(size,3)
);

cubes.instanceMatrix.setUsage(THREE.DynamicDrawUsage);

grid.add(cubes);
scene.add(grid);

const cube = new THREE.Object3D();
const center = (size + gap * (size - 1)) * -0.5;

grid.position.set(center, center, center);
if(s >= 10000){
camera.position.z = 25;
}
else if (s >= 100000){
camera.position.z = 75;
}
else if (s >= 1000000){
    camera.position.z = 100;
 }
else if (s >= 4000000){
    camera.position.z = 250;
  }
function animate() {
requestAnimationFrame(animate);

let i = 0;
for (let x = 0; x < size; x++) {
for (let y = 0; y < size; y++) {
for (let z = 0; z < size; z++) {
  cube.position.set(x, y, z);
  cube.updateMatrix();
  cubes.setMatrixAt(i, cube.matrix);
  i++;

}
}
}
/*
grid.rotation.x+=0.003;
grid.rotation.y+=0.003;
grid.rotation.z+=0.003;
*/
cubes.instanceMatrix.needsUpdate = true;

controls.update();
renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
animate();
}
document.getElementById('l').addEventListener('click', function() {
 s = document.getElementById('k').value;
 animates();
})

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

if i press  `<button type="button" id="l">Cal</button>` more than one time it puts a new animation even if there is already an existing one how do I remove the existing animation and put a new one

html

```
        <form class="form">
         <label>How much do you want to donate</label>
          <input type="number" id="k">
    <button type="button" id="l">Cal</button>
        </form>
      <script type="module" src="script.js">
      </script>
```

JavaScript

```
import * as THREE from "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.121.1/build/three.module.js";
import { OrbitControls } from "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.121.1/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js";
let s;

function animates(){ 
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

const scene = new THREE.Scene();
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
75,
window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
0.1,
1000
);
const controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

const grid = new THREE.Group();

const cubeSize = 0.5;
const size = Math.cbrt(s);
const gap = 0.01;

const geometry = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry(
cubeSize,
cubeSize,
cubeSize
);
const material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();
const cubes = new THREE.InstancedMesh(
geometry,
material,
Math.pow(size,3)
);

cubes.instanceMatrix.setUsage(THREE.DynamicDrawUsage);

grid.add(cubes);
scene.add(grid);

const cube = new THREE.Object3D();
const center = (size + gap * (size - 1)) * -0.5;

grid.position.set(center, center, center);
if(s <= 10000){
camera.position.z = 25;
}
else if (s <= 100000){
camera.position.z = 75;
}
else if (s <= 1000000){
    camera.position.z = 100;
    }
function animate() {
requestAnimationFrame(animate);

let i = 0;
for (let x = 0; x < size; x++) {
for (let y = 0; y < size; y++) {
for (let z = 0; z < size; z++) {
  cube.position.set(x, y, z);
  cube.updateMatrix();
  cubes.setMatrixAt(i, cube.matrix);
  i++;

}
}
}
/*
grid.rotation.x+=0.003;
grid.rotation.y+=0.003;
grid.rotation.z+=0.003;
*/
cubes.instanceMatrix.needsUpdate = true;

controls.update();
renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
animate();
}
document.getElementById('l').addEventListener('click', function() {
 s = document.getElementById('k').value;
 animates();
})
```

Comment: Please add a [mre] to the question.

Comment: is this better?

Comment: Kinda, it's more minimal, but it's still not reproducible. A stack snippet would be great, sure you'll get an answer quite fast, but now it's hard to see whats wrong without being able to run your code.

Comment: @0stone0 i just did but i put the javascript inside the html since it didnt work in the javascript part